# Postfix evaluation (small bug)

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

In this problem on the input there is a statement given into a postfix notation, and my task is to evaluate the given statement. I completely understand the algorithm and i will post my solution below. But for some reason it works for these: 1 2 3 * + 5 -,  1 1 1 - - 1 + 1 +, 1 2 + ... etc. but it doesn't work when there are numbers with multiple digits like this one: 100 20 -. My solution (java):

```
public class PostFixEvaluation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String expression = br.readLine();
    char exp[] = expression.toCharArray();

    ArrayStack<Integer> op = new ArrayStack<Integer>(100);

    int vrednost = 0;
    int dolzina = 0;
    int suma = 0;
    int res=0;
    int convert = 0;
    char ch;

    for(int i=0; i < exp.length; i++){
        ch = exp[i];
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
            convert = (int)ch-'0';
            op.push(convert);
            convert = 0;
        }
        else if(exp[i] == '+'){
                int x = op.pop();
                int y = op.pop();
                vrednost = x + y;
                op.push(vrednost);
                vrednost = 0;
        }
        else if(exp[i] == '-'){
                int x = op.pop();
                int y = op.pop();
                vrednost = y - x;
                op.push(vrednost);
                vrednost = 0;
        }
        else if(exp[i] == '*'){
                int x = op.pop();
                int y = op.pop();
                vrednost = y * x;
                op.push(vrednost);
                vrednost = 0;
        }
        else if(exp[i] == '/'){
                int x = op.pop();
                int y = op.pop();
                vrednost = y/x;
                op.push(vrednost);
                vrednost = 0;
        }
    } 

    res = op.pop();

    System.out.println(res);


    br.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here...

```
for(int i=0; i < exp.length; i++){
    ch = exp[i];
    if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
        convert = (int)ch-'0';
        op.push(convert);
        convert = 0;
    }
```

...is reading a single character, and pushing it onto your stack of numbers.  The problem is that you aren't checking to see whether that character is only the first digit of a number.

If your code encounters `"100 20 -"`, it will push `"1"`, `"0"`, `"0"`, `"2"`, `"0"` onto your number stack, instead of `"100"`, `"20"`.

You need to rewrite your parsing code to grab the entire number, instead of checking each character individually.

### Update

Regarding a better way to do that parsing, Java has some pretty good built-in `String` parsing tools.

In this case, I would recommend using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to parse `expression` instead of converting it to a `char[]`.  You can use methods like `hasNext()` and `hasNextInt()` to check whether there is more input, and whether that input is an `int`, and `next()` and `nextInt()` to read the next token.

e.g.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(expression);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {                     // while there more input...
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {                 // is the next token an int?
        int number = scanner.nextInt();         // read the next token as an integer
        op.push(number);
    } else {                                    // the next token is NOT an int
        String operator = scanner.next();       // read the next token as a String
        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            // same as before
        } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            // same as before
        } else if (operator.equals("*")) {
            // same as before
        } else if (operator.equals("/")) {
            // same as before
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but the thing is i don't know how to do that since i am a bit new in java, and i need help. :)

Comment: @user3075088 I've updated my answer with an explanation of how to parse the expression `String` directly, instead of as a `char[]`.